# Creating an XML file in Excel 2016

Tags: xml, excel

I am trying to create an XML file out of some information I have on a spreadsheet. I started following a tutorial however when I'm trying to import my schema it gives me an [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wnUhV.jpg). We are creating this so that a piece of software will take in the data and put it to use. The guy who I contact said it doesn't need a schema, so not sure how to go about creating this XML file without one?

Please see my [documents](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B7nMjkcbx2-xSGRWNE5rb0NxX2s?usp=sharing). Not quite sure what i am supposed to do but you will see a PDF from the company in regards to its design.

Maybe its very simple, I just don't know how to start!

Comment: Which bit of your code gives you an error?

Comment: Hi Tim, the error picture says line 1, column 37? But I dont have 37 columns so I'm not exactly sure :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, your .xml schema file is not a true .xsd schema file but just a snippet of your desired output. To export spreadsheet data to xml format, you need an [XSD](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/) schema file to map cell data to node data, specifying data types, occurrences, and lengths.

Below is a simple .xsd to match your desired output with `<PartsReports>` root, `<Parts>` repeated nodes with children as string formatted nodes: `<Part_No>`, `<Part_Prim_Desc>`, `<Part_Secd_Desc>`, `<Supp>`, `<SupplierCode>`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:element nillable="true" name="PartsReports">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence minOccurs="0">
                <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" nillable="true" name="Parts" form="unqualified">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:sequence minOccurs="0">
                            <xsd:element minOccurs="0" nillable="true" type="xsd:string" name="Part_No" form="unqualified"/>
                            <xsd:element minOccurs="0" nillable="true" type="xsd:string" name="Part_Prim_Desc" form="unqualified"/>
                            <xsd:element minOccurs="0" nillable="true" type="xsd:string" name="Part_Secd_Desc" form="unqualified"/>
                            <xsd:element minOccurs="0" nillable="true" type="xsd:string" name="Supp" form="unqualified"/>
                            <xsd:element minOccurs="0" nillable="true" type="xsd:string" name="SupplierCode" form="unqualified"/>
                        </xsd:sequence>
                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

Once the map is imported (Developer tab -> XML section -> Source) into the workbook, walk down each node and specify the range which would be the column ranges (i.e., Part_No - A2:A52312):

[image: Excel Map Screenshot]

Once all done, simply save the workbook in XML format in the usual Save As dialog.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<PartsReports xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Parts>
        <Part_No>E100001</Part_No>
        <Part_Prim_Desc>PCB IKON REV B</Part_Prim_Desc>
        <Part_Secd_Desc>223</Part_Secd_Desc>
        <Supp>H065</Supp>
        <SupplierCode>TN01492  - ISSUE B</SupplierCode>
    </Parts>
    <Parts>
        <Part_No>E100002</Part_No>
        <Part_Prim_Desc>PCB P095 AMF DISPLAY</Part_Prim_Desc>
        <Part_Secd_Desc/>
        <Supp>C104</Supp>
        <SupplierCode>P095</SupplierCode>
    </Parts>
    <Parts>
        <Part_No>E100003</Part_No>
        <Part_Prim_Desc>PCB P042 AMF</Part_Prim_Desc>
        <Part_Secd_Desc>(50 OFF)</Part_Secd_Desc>
        <Supp>H065</Supp>
        <SupplierCode>TN02367</SupplierCode>
    </Parts>
    <Parts>
        <Part_No>E100004</Part_No>
        <Part_Prim_Desc>PCB P010 KEYSTART</Part_Prim_Desc>
        <Part_Secd_Desc/>
        <Supp>H065</Supp>
        <SupplierCode>TN05852</SupplierCode>
    </Parts>
...
```

Comment: Thanks so much Parfait! I'm going to have a look at this now and run it by my contact to see if this will work. You're a star, thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Parfait, I have a new dilema. So that worked great, thanks again, however I need the tags  "Part_No", "Part_Prim_Desc", "Supp" and "SupplierCode" to become:

<PartNo> should be changed to <PartNumber>

<Part_Prim_Desc> should be changed to <Description Action="">

<Supp> should be changed to <VendorName>

<SupplierCode> should be changed to <VendorPart>

Comment: But when I try this I get an error in relation to the <Description Action=""> column

Comment: You need to add an attribute element to the xsd. However, adding text AND attribute is difficult in xsd and may not be allowed in Excel. Also, action must have some value. Right now, I can set up as `<Description Action=" "><Desc>textvalue</Desc></Description>`. Consider a raw XML export, then running XSLT (xml transformation) to final desired result.

Comment: Hi Parfait. Ok, so at the minute I am exporting a crystal report to excel then converting to XML using the XSD that you built. After seeing you mention XSLT I seen this option in the legacy XML options in crystal. I wonder if its easier exporting directly out of it? As crystal pulls the information from our MRP database, maybe its better to generate the XML directly from there? Are you familiar with Crystal reports at all and this function? I'll look into this today. Cheers

Comment: Try asking a new question for [Crystal Reports](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/crystal-reports) experts. Tag it in question. And be sure to show your efforts of code or application for reproducible example (no points down).